# Correlation between a variable and a pair of dependent variables?

Tags: correlation, modeling

I am working on a school project that focuses on linking rock fall danger with a variety of variables. I focus on precipitation and temperature - my research question is:

**Is there a statistically significant relationship (correlation) between the level of rock fall danger and the amount and type of precipitation?**

I have developed two hypotheses. The first one is that snowfall (i.e. relatively low temperature) will generally decrease rock fall danger - I expect negative correlation between the amount of precipitation and rock fall danger.

The second hypothesis says that rain (i.e. higher temperatures) will increase rock fall danger because - I expect positive correlation between the amount of precipitation and rock fall danger.

I have a database (ca. 600 rows) with (i) rock fall danger value (range 0 to 3 for none, low, medium, high danger), (ii) precipitation value, and (iii) average temperature.

I don't know how to statistically analyse this and get some meaningful results. The main problem as I see it is that I don't have a threshold value for what is snowfall and what is rainfall.

Comment: You could start by showing us some plots of the data.  Visualization is often a good starting point.